# Decomposition to 3NF

Tags: database-design, normalization

I need the help with following question as part of my *assignment / homework*

Provided the following structure

CLASS(**Reg-NO** ,**Unit-ID**,UnitTitle,Lecturer,Office)

The following functional dependencies are given.

- Unit_ID → UnitTitle
- Lecturer → Office
- UnitTitle → Lecturer

**Question 1 : Identify the form in which it exists.**

**Question 2 : Decompose to 3NF if it is not in that form.**

*For question 1:*
I Identified it to be in the **1NF** since it does not have **unique PK** as per the 2NF requirements.
It also meets the 1NF requirements, as per my observations.

*For question 2:*
I decomposed it to the following

- CLASS(Class-ID,Reg-NO)
- UNIT(Unit-ID,UnitTitle)
- LECTURER(Lecturer-ID,Lecturer,Office)

I have doubts about my answers and would like some help in reviewing them.

Also what format is structure in? (the : ENTITY(column1,column2,...) format) What's it called?

Comment: 2NF does not require a single candidate key.

Comment: we were given the following [Notes](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) for reference. I think my interpretation might be wrong. Could you explain more on that. @ypercubeᵀᴹ